# PyTorch YoloV5 model different results?

Tags: python, list, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo

I am trying to do a object detection on videos , I have used YoloV5S . There are the two methods of identifying the object.

**1) first is from loading the model from torch.hub.load()**

**2) Second is from python detect.py**

I am getting different results on the same video from both methods instead of same results . If I just use

```
!python detect.py --weights 'yolov5s.pt' --conf-thres=0.25 --source /home/hamza/Desktop/House_Video.mp4
```

I am getting results with detected objects of different count , for example in the last frame of this video I am getting 3 chairs, 1 dining table and 1 clock but if I use the below code **(torch.hub.load)** . I am getting 3 chairs and 1 dining table . Same goes for all frames , there are some missing objects in this method which first method has .

**My code :**

```
import cv2, torch
model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'yolov5s')
model.conf = 0.25

list_of_original_frames = []
list_of_detected_classes_in_all_frames = []
detected_classes = []
check_dict = {}

def detect_video(video_path):

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
    while (cap.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret == False:
            break
        list_of_original_frames.append(frame)
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    for file in list_of_original_frames:
        results = model(file)
        new_df = results.pandas()
        new_result = new_df.xywh[0]['name']
        list_of_detected_classes_in_all_frames.append(new_result.tolist())
   
    
    for outer_loop in list_of_detected_classes_in_all_frames:
        for inner_loop in outer_loop:
            if inner_loop:
                detected_classes.append(inner_loop)

    for iterate in detected_classes:
        if iterate not in check_dict:
            check_dict[iterate] = 1
        else:
            check_dict[iterate] = check_dict[iterate] + 1
    
    return check_dict
video_path = '/home/hamza/Desktop/House_Video.mp4'
check_dict = detect_video(video_path)
```

Which part I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', path='path/to/best.pt') # default

model = torch.hub.load('path/to/yolov5', 'custom', path='path/to/best.pt', source='local') # local repo

Comment: I don't think this addresses the question. It does not sound to me like OP has a hard time loading the model, I think they're looking for help using it.